# Read double value from TCP/IP connection Java

Tags: java, tcp, double, tcpclient, datainputstream

I need to read the double speed value of a driving simulator over tcp/ip.

I tried it like this:

```
Socket s = new Socket(server, port);
InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
System.out.println(dis.readDouble());
```

With BigEndian = true in the configuration of the simulator I get values like this which make no sense:

```
-1.565600306167059E-119
 2.6794374850840603E-248
-2.8742899426422626E-168
-1.858946187722445E-277
 1.0067114608326767E54
-0.001054984626127145
-3.862596704088319E-110
 4.618147910668653E-193
-9.491033037580185E290
```

With BigEndian = false the first output is the correct value followed by 7 nonsense values and so on like this:

```
109.94424404374932
1.0152777137342873E132
3.810036543451522E-70
5.888865755856121E100
-3.430929070370842E67
1.0937105040100144E-105
-1.809009002903045E-259
2.7053994656972186E-23
105.04537620848295
1.304469700127963E126
-1.3728712552450811E284
...
```

**This is what wireshark shows for 1 packet:**

[image: wireshark output]

**Does anyone have an idea how to get only the correct values?**

Comment: Do you know how the data is encoded? Is there a specification? If not, how do you know they're doubles?

Comment: I dont know how the data is encoded. This is the SendDefinition where i can set double as Datatype: <PacketDefinition> =  
((<VariableNames> ,<Datatype> [,<Defaultvalue> , <Multiplier> , <Offset>]));

Comment: TCP is byte-oriented, so you need to make sure that the whole double has been received by the socket before decoding it. Assuming double is 8 byte, check that the socket has more than 8 bytes before calling readDouble. (C programmer)

Comment: Your definition suggests there should be a variable name and a data type, but I can't see a name there. Your reader should be attempting to read a name, then a type you need to decode followed by the data.

Comment: @FormerNcp `readDouble()` already does exactly that.